# What is the basis generally used in software for the natural cubic splines?

Tags: regression, regularization, splines

Of course there are many natural cubic spline bases, but reading through documentation (mgcv, splines in R and patsy, scipy.interpolate and csaps in Python) sheds no light on which ones are used in practice (in particular, for penalized spline regression). So, does anyone know? i.e. is anyone able to give an explicit formula for a basis for the natural cubic splines which are used in (at least one of) these software packages?